# Indexing does not find exe (win10)

Tags: windows-10

I have some folder C:\custom installations where I have some programs that are not installed via msi installers.

Now, I would like to have this folder indexed, so that I can use Win key + "someApplicationName" to call the exe.

However, someApplicationName is not found... I tried adding the folder (with all subfolders) in "Indexing Options" but that does not seem to help. Do I have to do anything else or is it not possible at all?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The path containing the exe is indexed, the indexing options are set to also index EXE files, and indexing is completed. Yet, it still does not find the exe when searching in "documents". I do have the feeling that this should work, and the other suggested worarounds should not be required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are confusing Content Indexing with [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) Lookup.

[To get the results you want](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), Hit Win + Break to display system.cpl, and select "Advanced System Settings" -> "Environment Variables". In the "System Variables" box, Double click the variable "PATH". At the end of the string, add `;c:\path\to\folder\;`.

Once added to the PATH, you can invoke executables in the directory just as you suggest. If another version of an exe by the same name launches, just move your folder path further to the Left in the PATH string, or put it at the beginning of the string (but be careful that you don't have any exes that share the names of system or application executables).

Content indexing is something different. it indexes metadata about the files, and information about their Contents as well, so that it is fast to search inside a large number of content files. Content Indexing should/would not do anything with an executable, because it is not content.

Comment: Thanks, I have added it. Do I have to do anything else other than restarting explorer to get it working? Because right now it doesn't. Also, if indexing does not search exe files, why is exe in the list of "data types" in "Indexing Options"?

Comment: If you hit Win + R, and type in the name, does it launch correctly?

Comment: Yes, that works fine

Comment: but when you type the name of the exe, it does not appear in your start menu?

Comment: yes, exactly (random-words for filling minimum of words)

Comment: even if you put .exe on the end?

Comment: ah, with the full name it will be found!! Then, how can I get windows to help me out? There is no other application or even file that starts like this exe. Normally, windows would show the entry with even few characters typed

Comment: I know, that issue has annoyed me back to Win Vista. Haven't found a good answer. Is your system configured to display extensions? I always turn on extensions, but perhaps it would change matters if you used the default "hide file extensions for known file types".

Comment: actually, it now even works without .exe... but the name without is still very long :/

Comment: A workaround is to create shortcuts to the application in some startmenu folder... Maybe, I will go with this